# Adding headers to ajax request fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, header, jsonp

This would seem to be very straightforward, but I cannot get additional HTTP headers added into a request that I'm attempting to make. I've watched via the browser developer tools as well as with BurpSuite. I'm using JSONP since this is a cross-site call, but that shouldn't matter.  I'm stumped and looking for some guidance.

I need to add a token/value in the header of the request I'm making of from a 3rd parties Rest API for authentication. I've stripped the code out into a sample page for debugging purposes. Here is the sample that I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function getData() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://<somesite>.com/<path>",
        accept: "application/json",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) { 
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
          xhr.setRequestHeader("x-token","<token value>"); 
        }, 
        data: {
          select: "timeZoneId"
        },
        success: function (data, status) {
          debugger;
          alert("Sucess");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
          debugger;
          alert("Error! :" + xhr.status);
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="getData()">Submit</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've gone through all kinds of contortions with adding the x-token as a header, but it's never getting added into the request, that I can see. The result of the request is always a 401 unauthorized error, which is the expected error if an invalid/missing x-token is being passed. As I've mentioned, an inspection of the headers does not show the x-token.

The headers that I do see are:

```
GET /redzone/public/bi/v_completeddataitem?callback=jQuery36009809687059838048_1648150351509&select=timeZoneId&_=1648150351510 HTTP/2
Host: <somesite>.com
Cookie: AWSALBCORS=f+1AWICQyRddSBjj6CNFH6f6XAnVjPOqAMq1JcPj9CCN1x1Izv1cFFXFKo7IKop53Lw4Y95mWWRjzHRAtOwTGccbwbvS8DBCDxJZY8WA9dEwu2Z/XKPeiSV+rAsb
Sec-Ch-Ua: "(Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="99"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.74 Safari/537.36
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Windows"
Accept: */*
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: script
Referer: http://localhost/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

JSONP works by injecting a `<script>` element with a `src` attribute.

There is no way to set request headers on a `<script>` element.

This is one of the many limitations of JSONP.

Use XMLHttpRequest or fetch to request JSON with CORS instead.

---

One of the headers you are setting is `Accept: application/json` which doesn't make sense since the **only** data format you can parse using JSONP is JSONP (which is a subset of `text/javascript`).

I have a hunch that the problem is that the third party doesn't support cross-origin requests and you are trying to hack around it by using JSONP. That won't work since JSONP requires they explicitly support JSONP (just as a modern cross-origin request requires that they explicitly support CORS).

If the third-party doesn't support cross-origin requests then you need to make the request from somewhere that is not the browser. e.g. proxy it through your own server.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Agreed about the extra header - Accept: application/json   I was including it as just a test to see if the header actually goes through.
Your correct about the 3rd party and CORS.  I was trying to bypass it by using jsonp, but now that you've pointed out that you've pointed out the issue I'll see if I can either get them to enable CORS or go with the XMLHtttp route.

Comment: @JeffBryant — It isn't an either / or. If you use XHR or if you use fetch then the server needs to use CORS to grant your JS permission to read the response.